# Question, meta-question, meta-meta-question

Tags: discussion, meta, wrong-answers, asking-questions

First, I have a simple problem, namely, how to embed source code or HTML in Open Office Org Presentation (OOoP).

Then I came to SO to ask this question, and I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281025/how-to-format-a-block-of-code-within-a-presentation/281071#281071) already exists, with no good answer, 2 years old. The answer suggest that if I know how to embed HTML then I should do the job, but that is the point.

I thought to ask another question, but it would risk being closed as a duplicate. I was in doubt what to do. Then I came to meta to ask for guidance. That was my second problem.

I started typing the new question and I discovered that another question already with this subject [is here in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84331/ask-question-with-wrong-answer-again). I read it carefully. It said there to not ask the question again. So I wrote some comments, trying to get some answers for these two problems. Also, I did all the tips in the first question (comments, vote the answer down, write more info, etc., to try to bump that question up).

The problem is that none of that worked. I got no attention from the original question, and no comments from the meta question. Now I have a third problem: what should I do? This is the meta-meta-question.

Edited:
Question of order:

1. If you want to answer how to embed HTML in Open Office Presentation, you should go to  [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281025/how-to-format-a-block-of-code-within-a-presentation/281071#281071).
2. If you want to answer how other tools (like voting down, bounties, etc.) might help me regarding the problem on raising attention on question 1, you should go to [question 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84331/ask-question-with-wrong-answer-again).
3. If you want to discuss how this mingled things happens, here is the right place. How come I needed to ask a third question? What we really should discuss here? The fact that people don't like to answer comments in someone else's questions? The fact people don't like to ask questions in comments in someone else's questions? How can improve the site to avoid this to happen? (Maybe it is a discussion between the big-dogs, and we have not too much to add here. Just please, remember, what I really need is an answer to question 1, please, please...)

2nd edition. Accepting the suggestion bellow, I asked this [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505515/how-do-i-embed-source-code-or-html-in-open-office-org-presentations-without-using) regarding problem 1.

Comment: and you're too new to add a bounty...

Comment: @zzz where did you see that? Couldn't find anything telling one need to be member for X days, just have 75 reputation.

Comment: But I would do a bounty to a question that I would have no control if the answer is useful to me. I'm not the owner. For a first bounty in my history, with only 200 rep. losing some privileges, that would be too much for me. Also, the question has already a answer accepted, and I don't know if the owner is willing to un-accept it.

Comment: @Shadow around here it makes plenty of sense to measure newness by reputation instead of / in addition to time.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I couldn't remember what the limit was specifically, but he had `< 100` rep at the time, so I assumed he couldn't set a bounty yet.

Comment: This is a meta-meta-comment.

Comment: Should've posted this on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @zzz bounty requires 75 reputation not 100. :) @Beco - the answer does not have to be un-accepted bounty can be rewarded to totally different answer. However losing privileges is indeed heavy cost..

Comment: To @zzzzBov @Shadow Wizard @geekosaur @Adam Davis @kivetros @justkt : I propose a new tool: (any of) you bounty my question with (one) 50 bucks, and I pay you back as soon as I get enough rep to keep the privilege of retag questions. How about it? ;)

Comment: @DrBeco, It'd be better for the system if you just used it as designed. Gain the 50 rep needed to make a low bounty, and you'll be able to add the bounty yourself. Just find a few easy questions and write up a couple answers, you'll have 50 more rep in no time.

Comment: @zzzzBov I just won a bounty of +50 from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475790/how-to-disassemble-the-main-function-of-a-stripped-application)! Nice, isn't it? I put the earned points to immediate use in a bounty in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505515/how-do-i-embed-source-code-or-html-in-open-office-org-presentations-without-using). ;)

Answer (score 4):

In cases where previous questions can have multiple answers in different scenarios, I believe it's acceptable ask a more directed question, addressing the previous question to prevent duplicate or misleading answers:

> How do I embed source code or HTML in Open Office Org Presentations without using screenshots?

The previous question you cite is different enough to me that it'd be worth asking your question anyway.

Comment: I'm accepting this as a good advice for problem 2. Not for problem 1, not for problem 3. Thanks ! :)

Comment: The new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505515/how-do-i-embed-source-code-or-html-in-open-office-org-presentations-without-using). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bounty sounds like your best option.

Even small bounty of 50 or 100 should draw at least *some* attention and maybe from the right people.

Comment: Considering my rep. and the comment I did above, I don't think this is a solution for the 1st problem.

Comment: @Dr Beco - the bounty will attract new answers regardless, since bounties aren't related to accepted or not accepted answers, but are given by you before the expiration date.

Comment: @DrBeco fair enough. Fingers crossed for your new question! :)

Comment: @justkt Thanks for explaining that part. I didn't know I had such control. @Shadow, did you cross your finger? I need another hand.:) It is not working... Unless the problem is unsolvable! 66 views and no pertinent answer. Bounty ends in 4 days now! Oh boy... [____ :( ____](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505515/how-do-i-embed-source-code-or-html-in-open-office-org-presentations-without-using)

Comment: @DrBeco sorry to hear.... all 20 fingers crossed. ;)