# Is it acceptable to re-ask a question when the existing answers aren't helpful?

Tags: support, asking-questions, wrong-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask question with wrong answer again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84331/ask-question-with-wrong-answer-again)

I asked a question some time ago and the 2 answers didnt help very much.   I want to ask the question again - is it ok to raise it as a new question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, it is not.** Your "new" question will get closed as a duplicate of your previous question.

What *is* acceptable, however, is to revisit your old question, editing it to improve and clarify what you're asking, providing additional details about why the existing answers aren't helping you, and possibly setting a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) to encourage new activity and answers.